# Azure web service api usage per user insights

Tags: api, azure, analytics

We have a API (written in .NET Core 3.1), published to Azure Web Services. This API talks to a database for authentication. After a succesfull authentication, the API connects to other databases, depending the user that logs in.

Now we came to the part of insights. I want to know:

- The datetime the API is called
- By which client
- What end-point was triggered

I'm not sure how I can get this insights. Does Azure provide such a functionality? Or do I have to write records myself in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm sure it will be possible in Azure insights, it does charge us for usage. That is fine since it can provide a lot of statistics.

But because we only want just a small amount of information, we've created middleware that does collect the data and writes that to our database. For now this is sufficient.